# Почему не работает телеграм бот?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

[image: Код]

Почему не работает бот ? Написал простенький код, запустил через VScode, нажимаю в тг старт, ничего не работает

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе - текстом, не картинкой**.

Comment: Не прикрепляйте код в виде картинок. Делайте это с помощью редактора текста вопроса